# How to filter one or more than one attribute in one method?

Tags: java

I have a `Student` class (`String name`, `String DOB`, `int age` and `int grade`), then I create an `ArrayList<Student>` and add some new `Student` to the list.

I want to filter that list, using only one method but can filter by name, by DOB, by name and DOB and age, you get the idea. I tried the overload but I can't handle the String - String and int - int.

Can someone show me the way to get out of this problem?

```
public void filter(int age) {
    for (Student x : this.arraylist) {
        if (x.getAge() == age) {
            System.out.println(x.getName());
        }
    }
}


public void filter(int grade) {
    for (Student x : this.arraylist) {
        if (x.getGrade() == grade) {
            System.out.println(x.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

If I write `filterByAge(int age)` and `filterByGrade(int age)`, everything will be OK, but I want to overloads the method filter....

Comment: show the code and error you got

Comment: `public void filter(int age) {
//
}`
and now is overload method filter:
`public void filter(int grade) {
//
}`
Of course I can't do that, but if you dont overload then how to filter the grade and the age? (Notes that you have to use just one filter method).

Comment: Post the code with error you are facing edit your question

Comment: You can't have two methods with the same name and same argument types. It's as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `Filter` interface and just have one `filter` function that takes a Filter as a parameter.

```
interface Filter {
    boolean filter(Student x);
}
```

In your `Student` class, you can do

```
public void filter(Filter f) {
    for (Student x : this.arraylist) {
        if (f.filter(x)) {
            System.out.println(x.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can call

```
filter(new Filter() {
    @Override
    boolean filter(Student x) {
        return x.getAge() == 30;
    }
});
```

Or

```
filter(new Filter() {
    @Override
    boolean filter(Student x) {
        return x.getGrade() == 5;
    }
});
```

I'm sure using the new Java 8 lambda thingies, you could get a simpler format, easier to code and easier to read, but I'm not familiar with those as of yet.

Comment: You could make Filter take a generic type, rather than a Student object. And yes Java 8 does have a filter method on its own.

Comment: The abstract class should really be an interface. Java 8's equivalent is called a Predicate: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html.

Comment: I don't know where to put the `filter(new filter() {`, I have a Student Class and a StudentList Class (with one attribute `ArrayList<Student>`

Comment: You don't put `filter(new filter() {` anywhere in those classes. You put it where you *use* those classes. In other words, you use it instead of calling `filterByAge(30);`.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to overload the functions in the way that you want because, since they both have one `int` passed in, Java cannot determine which one that you would like to use.

For example, could you determine which of the functions that was used here:

```
filter(30);
```

You need to change the function names in order to accomplish this.

EDIT:

Another thought that I had was that you could add a flag determining what you wanted to sort by.

For Example:

```
public enum FilterType {
    AGE, GRADE
}

public void filter(int value, FilterType type) {
    switch (type) {
    case FilterType.AGE:
        for (Student x : this.arraylist) {
            if (x.getAge() == age) {
                System.out.println(x.getName());
            }
        }
        break;
    case FilterType.GRADE:
        for (Student x : this.arraylist) {
            if (x.getGrade() == grade) {
                System.out.println(x.getName());
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would love to see them. ;)

Comment: There. :) Not exactly the thing the OP wanted, (which, as you pointed out, is impossible) but a close enough alternative...